# In print of for loop function exit is value +1 than expected

Tags: python, for-loop, iteration, exit-code

I'm still begginer and trying to solve a task for my begginer coding course. I can't understand why in input 1 program works fine but if I input 2 instead of values 66, 132 it prints next sequence of number 132, 198. I feel I'm close to solution but not quite sure what am I doing wrong.

```
i=int(input())
   for n in range(0, i):
       print(66*i)
       i=i+1
```

Comment: Hi. Don't change the i inside the loop. You probably meant to do `print(66*n)` and not `print(66*i)` anyway

Comment: I did but it then prints sequence 0,66,132 and it needs to start printing from 66.

Comment: @LaCodeM, use ```for n in range(1, i)```

Answer (score 1):

Let's go through it step by step:

- You input `2`, so the value of `i` starts out as `2`.
- `range(0, i)` will be `range(0, 2)` and thus create a range containing two entries (meaning the loop's body will execute twice).
- On the first iteration, `i`'s value is still 2 because that's what it started as and you haven't changed it yet. So `print(66*i)` will print `66*2 = 132`.
- Now you execute `i = i + 1`, so the value of `i` is now `3`.
- So on the second iteration, `i`'s value is 3 and `print(66*i)` will print `66*3 = 198`.
- Now `i` is incremented to 4 (which doesn't matter because `i` isn't used again) and then the loop ends because it went through both iterations.

The value of `n` was 0 and 1 respectively during the two iterations, but that didn't matter because you never used `n`.

Comment: I need to print 1*n on first iteration, 2*n on second, 3*n on third etc. It's fine but it starts with 0 when I input 1. So instead 1*66=66, it prints 0*66=0.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is simple: you are multiplying 66 by `i` instead of `n`. Use `print(66*n)` and it should be fine. `i` is inputted as 2, so 66* 2 is 132. Then you increment i, so it becomes 3, and 66 * 3 is 198.

Answer (score 0):

Multiply with `n` instead of `i` so it loops form the start
you can make the start of the loop `1` instead of `0` if it's bothering you